# How to Fix "throw new Error(`If callbackSuccess is supplied so must callbackError`);"

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, async-await, callback

I have a script to call the GeoTab API to retrieve data for some vehicles. The script is failing.

```
async function getFuelTypeDevices(){

    fuelTypeDevices =  await api.call("Get",{ 

            "typeName":"Device",

            "search":{ 

                    "groups": fuelType,

                "fromDate":new Date().toISOString(),

                },},

            function(results){

            for (var x =0; x < results.length; x++){

                    fuelTypeDevices[x] = results[x].id; 

            }});}
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/basillatif/Desktop/CALSTART.nosync/FritoLay_Main/FritolayScripts/node_modules/mg-api-js/dist/webpack:/GeotabApi/lib/GeotabApi.js:71
throw new Error(`If callbackSuccess is supplied so must callbackError`);
```

I need to catch the callbackError. Once I catch the error in this function I get an error further down in my code saying that fuelTypeDevices is undefined. What is the best way to catch the callback error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue and call the API with the same code by downgrading the version of the Geotab node package to `mg-api-js@2.0.3`